# How to switch to client's developer console in apple

Tags: ios

I am new to apple developer console and my client provided me permissions and authorised me as an admin.

But still I can't create Bundle and add an application from my console.  Most Probably, I need to switch my account like we need to do it in google developer console.

Please guide me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect on: [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) -> My Apps -> Press the "+" to add a new app

Comment: I did that, and i first need to add a Bundle.... it lead me to unauthorised action page, but client has provided me admin rights